# Could Not Connect to Local Server in Xcode

Tags: node.js, xcode, swift, localhost, alamofire

Trying to Connect to a local server from Xcode. I have imported an Alamofire Pod into my Xcode project and run the following command in xcode

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000" , parameters: ["code": "123"]).responseJSON {
                response in
                print ("Hello", response)
            }
```

I recieve the following error in Xcode when running on iOS device.

```
 FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13d84f7f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
```

I know the local is serving is running. When I call the following function on the command line:

```
$ node index.js
Running at http://localhost:3000
```

In the browser the following is shown:

```
Cannot GET /
```

My .js file is the following:

```
 var buffer = require('buffer');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var crypto = require('crypto');
 var express = require('express');
 var request = require('request');
 var url = require('url');
 var app = express();

var config = {
  clientId: '',
  clientSecret: '',
  callbackUrl: '',
  encryptionSecret: '',
  endpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com',
 };

 var secretString = config.clientId + ':' + config.clientSecret;
 var authHeader = 'Basic ' + new  buffer.Buffer(secretString).toString('base64');

 // app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // TODO - Figure out why this should be here
 app.use(bodyParser.json()); // TODO - Figure out why this should be here

 var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var address = server.address();

  console.log('Running at http://localhost:%s', address.port);
 });

 app.post('/swap', function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);

  if (!req.body || !req.body.hasOwnProperty('code')) {
    console.log('Swap: missing auth code');
    res.status(550).send('Permission Denied');

    return;
  }

  formData = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: config.callbackUrl,
    code: req.body.code
  };

  console.log('Swap: POST to %s', url.resolve(config.endpoint, '/api/token'), formData);

  request.post({
    url: url.resolve(config.endpoint, '/api/token'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': authHeader,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  form: formData,
  }, function(error, response, body) {

  if (error) {
     console.log('Swap: Error - ', error);
     res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');

     return;
   }

    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
     debug('Swap: response: ', response.statusCode);
     res.status(550).send('Permission Denied');

    return;
    }

   var tokenData = JSON.parse(body);

   console.log('Swap: tokenData - ', tokenData);

   res.status(200).set({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }).send(tokenData);

 });

});
```

Comment: Try to make a normal `GET` and post what's getting

Comment: You have **https** in your Alamofire.request but you actually running **http**

Comment: just changed to **http**, still getting the same error. Not entirely sure what you mean by that @VictorSigler

Comment: Additionally my `Alamofire.framework`, `Foundation.framework`, and `Pods.Framework`, are in red but the project still builds and I am still able to import Alamofire into my swift files

Comment: @cnichs27 "Cannot GET /" in the browser means that your node.js application doesn't handle GET requests - you can add a GET handler and re-check if it works from browser. Regarding the error itself, check if [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/749) is helpful - if you are running this on the device, then it actually doesn't have access to "localhost:3000", try it in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks @BorisSerebrov! I'm ganna try that out. As for running it on the device, I get the same error on the simulator as well

Comment: Once you have a GET request working from the desktop browser, check if it works in the mobile browser in the simulator.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov, your original comment is now making sense to me. I am able to connect to the server if I run from the desktop and not from the mobile browser. Thank you!

Comment: So did you solve the issue? Actually you should be able to connect to localhost if you run in the simulator. If you run on the device you need to use an IP address inside your network (something like http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000).

Comment: @Boris, do I just put that instead of `http://localhost:3000`? Issue is solved on the simulator, as for the device, I must follow your directions. Don't know whether to mark this as solved or not!

Comment: You need to find the IP address of the machine you launched node.js on. Usually local network addresses look like 192.168.0.100 (this is just an example, your address may differ). Once you know the IP, put `http://192.168.0.100:3000` (replace with your IP) instead of `http://localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the summary of the discussion from comments:

1) Initially the node.js application only had a route for `POST` requests. This makes debugging more complex. Add a route for `GET` requests, so you can check `http://localhost:3000` from the browser. Now check if it works in the desktop browser and in the simulator browser to confirm the general node application availability.

2) Address like `http://localhost:3000` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000` only works on the same machine where the node.js application is running. This includes the iOS simulator, but will not work with such address on the device.

3) To test on the device - replace the localhost address with your local network IP address. The local network address usually looks like `192.168.xxx.xxx` and can be found in network settings.

To actually run this setup in production, you will need a server, where you run the node.js application, to have a public real IP address or domain name and you will connect to it using something like `http://my.app.domain.or.ip:3000`.